# WordPress ContactForm7 datepicker field - disable/block specific dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker, contact-form-7

I currently have a WordPress site installed where users can book a tour of our facility (we are a university). I have used the ContactForm7 plugin to create a form within a page where visitors can enter their contact information and then can use a datepicker field to select the specific date that they want to take their tour on.

My question is (I've searched high and low for a solution to this but to no avail) is there a way that I can disable or block specific dates from being selected in this datepicker field in the form? For example, there are a number of days when tours are not available (i.e. holidays and other days when tour staff are not on campus) so I don't want these dates to be selectable.

Is there a way to do this within the plugin, or is there any other way I can do it, whether it's using a script or through another plugin?

My colleague showed me a site that uses a jQuery/JS datepicker field in their tour booking form (this is NOT a WordPress/ContactForm7 form however) and they are able to block specific dates when tours aren't available, so I'm assuming it should be possible...somehow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

EDIT:

I found the code below and the website sounds like it'll do exactly what I'm looking for (using a method similar to one of the answers below it looks like) but I can't really figure out how to add it to my site so that it works. I've added it in the header.php file of my theme, and I've set the id to "#DisabledDates" - which is what I've set the datepicker field id to on the form as well...but the dates that I set for the "unavailableDates" are still selectable...any ideas?

```
<?php if ($post->ID==16) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailableDates = ["9-5-2013", "10-5-2013", "11-5-2013", "12-5-2013", "13-5-2013", "14-5-2013", "15-5-2013", "16-5-2013", "17-5-2013", "18-5-2013", "19-5-2013", "20-5-2013", "21-5-2013", "22-5-2013", "23-5-2013", "24-5-2013"];

    jQuery(function($){
        $( "#DisabledDates" ).datepicker({
            minDate: 5,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
                if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                    return [true, ""];
                } else {
                    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's where I found it (it looks like a plugin that existed to extend CF7 with a datepicker field before the datepicker was added to the plugin...but I'm assuming it should still work similarly?): https://github.com/relu/contact-form-7-datepicker/issues/37

Answer (score 0):

You will have to access FTP to put a function somewhere in the CF7 files.

OR You can possibly find the class Wordpress uses and filter those dates out.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the response. I'm not very familiar with the CF7 files (I just installed it as a plugin) - any idea where that would have to go? And what that function would look like?

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by two types

- set mindate and maxdate
- when you open the datepicker and change month/year it will fire an event beforeShowDay with each date on that month and year, and you can check for each date in that function with your date range array or object and return true or false. If false return that date will be deactive and on true that date will be active

Check out this link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

The description says this: "Set the beginning and end dates as actual dates (new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26)), as a numeric offset from today (-20), or as a string of periods and units ('+1M +10D')"

Comment: Hi Tate, thanks for the response. To be honest I'm not as familiar with jQuery as I am with other languages...the datepicker in CF7 has optional fields for "id" "class" "min" "max" and "step"...I understand what these do based on the CF7 FAQ, but are these the options you're talking about, or are you talking about these options at a lower level (i.e. within the plugin files somewhere?)...I found the date.php file which I believe defines how the datepicker functions, but I don't know how or where to add whatever it is that I would need to add! Any ideas?

Comment: Similar to what @Josh Riley said below, you will need to put this in "the plugin files somewhere", via FTP.